# CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW What does it do?

Tags: c++, c, windows, class, bit

```
structure.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
```

That is a code line I found for registering a window's class and setting the resize setting but how does it work, what will the value of structure's `style` be?

The pipe symbol in the middle `|` is the bitwise `OR` so will it set `style` to the combination of bits from `CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW` so what will it mean for Windows, how will it know if both are set, one is or none are?

Maybe I am over-thinking...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I did and still didn't understand. What will the result of the bit-wise combination mean for windows?

Comment: when `CS_HREDRAW` bit is set, then horizontal size change causes redraw of entire window. otherwise horizontal size change causes redraw only of newly exposed area. ditto for `CS_VREDRAW`, where the `V` stands for "vertical".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason the flags can be OR'd is because they were purposefully written to not cancel each other out.

If you look at the values of those flags you will see that:

```
CS_HREDRAW = 0x0001 = 0000 0000 0000 0001
CS_VREDRAW = 0x0002 = 0000 0000 0000 0010
```

The result of ORing these flags is:

```
COMBINED = 0x0003 = 0000 0000 0000 0011
```

This is known as a [Bit Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx)

The function knows which bits correspond to each flag, so looking at which bits are set will tell it how to behave.